# What's so cool about jQuery?

Tags: jquery

...other than those neat little fade/slide effects, that is.

Comment: Actually, the fade/slide effects are among the worse features of jQuery :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element selectors, AJAX framework, extensibility, DOM manipulation, cross-browser compilance, tons of good plugins and etc. jQuery is awesome time saver.

Answer (score 1):

You can summarize it in a few words: "Code less do more"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using it comparing to pure JavaScript? If not it's worth trying!